# How change Facebook like button size and image?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I have this piece of code that works for adding a Facebook like button to my iOS app using Swift. Now I want to change size of the button. I tried to change from 100 to something else for example 160. But button size doesn't change and stays the same. I read in one of the threads that I should use FBSDKLikeButton instead of FBSDKLikeControl if I want to change the size, then I noticed that I'll lose the chance to show the counter that shows how many people have already liked my page (i.e. likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount is not applicable anymore). So, is there a solution to this? Can I change my button size without losing the ability to show the BoxCount? Also, how do I change the image of my facebook like button if I want to use FBSDKLikeControl?

```
import UIKit
    import Parse
    import Social

    class NewsPageViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            likeButton()
        }
        func likeButton() {
            var likeButton:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
            likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/JCVDonline/?fref=ts"
            likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
            likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(16,20, 100, 50)
            self.view.addSubview(likeButton)
        }

}
```

Comment: Tried to transform the button?

Comment: That was awesome advice! I added this line "likeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2)" and now the likeButton is resized. just one more question though, does scaling with CGAffineTransformMakeScale reduce the quality of likeButton image?

Comment: And, is it possible do change the image of likeButton as well?

Comment: I guess FaceBook's likeButton's image is a vector. That would mean the quality does not decrease but I can't tell for sure, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.transform` property of the `UIButton` like this:

```
likeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2) //doubles the button's size
```

**Note** that this may reduce the button's image's quality. Possibly that will not happen if the image is a vector. Go ahead and try! ;)

Hope this helps